# MS Access Form populating certain fields in an excel file

Tags: ms-access

I have the below code that takes certain fields from my MS Access (A small Hotel Reservation Database)form and populates defined cells in the said Excel file.

```
Dim objXLApp As Object
Dim objXLBook As Object
Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objXLBook = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("Y:\123files\File\Hotel Reservation.xls")
objXLApp.Application.Visible = True

objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2") = Me.GuestFirstName & " " & GuestLastName
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("C2") = Me.PhoneNumber
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("E2") = Me.cboCheckInDate
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("F2") = Me.cboCheckOutDate
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("H2") = Me.RoomType
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("I2") = Me.RoomNumber
End Sub
```

Me.RoomType is a combo box with the row source being a 3 column query. When I run the code the excel file lists the first column in my query instead of the 2 column which is the one I need, how can I direct it to add the second column of my query instead of the first? Also, how can I move to the next line in the excel file when I switch to a new customers form in my Access file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the Column property of your combo box to extract the value you want.  Column numbering starts with zero, so the second will be Column(1).  Try this:

```
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("H2") = Me.RoomType.Column(1)
```

For more information, see Method 2 at [How to Use the Column Property of a Combo Box to Update a Text Box](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209738)

I'm unsure what to say in response to your second question.  I think you should specify your Ranges at runtime by concatenating the column letter and a row number variable.

```
Dim lngExcelRow as Long
lngExcelRow = 2
objXLBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & lngExcelRow) = [something ...]
```

Then to write to a different worksheet row, change the value for lngExcelRow.

Comment: Thanks HansUp, but the Column(1) returned the error "Method or Data member not found" and it highlights .column