# Generate an Excel file from a template

Tags: excel, ms-access, report

Regarding creating an automatic Excel sheet from an Excel template for a user that uses data from the database.

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to fill out the fields in this [Excel sheet](http://1drv.ms/1KZXRrJ) (and have the graph automatically change) and for the Excel sheet to pop up as a new file for the user (i.e. the template would stay untouched). You'll see in the Excel sheet that there are a number of cells that need to be filled from Access. I have a query in Access PER CELL that needs to be filled.

So, essentially I have 14 queries and I need the results of those queries to appear in the cells of a local version of an Excel template.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673681/ms-access-form-populating-certain-fields-in-an-excel-file) but I'm having troubles connecting the dots to my actual task that needs to be done.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to your database directly from Excel to a custom view for each 'template'? I imagine if you hooked up chart series to each of the columns, the user can just go to the "Data" tab and hit "Refresh". Here is a link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-Import-external-data-9967afd8-85ee-4df3-aa06-753bcc1a2724

Comment: That's a really interesting method! I love the simplicity. So would I create 14 links in that case? One for each query? I can't easily format the data from the query into a table within access first because the data isn't similar (Although each query is only generating a 1x1 table, a 'count' with a bunch of 'where' clauses)